# Proof: if $AB=BA$, prove that $(AB)^2 = A^2B^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I got a little stuck with this proof. It is given that $AB=BA$.

Proof: $(AB)^2 = A^2 \cdot B^2$

I have been thinking of several ways to solve it. I got to this point:

$(AB)^2 = AB\cdot AB = BA\cdot AB = B\cdot A^2\cdot B$

But I don't know how to proceed. I think I am missing some general rule.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How about $(AB)^2 = (AB)(AB) = A(BA)B = A(AB)B = (AA)(BB) = A^2 B^2$? Are the steps clear, or would you like me to explain further?

Comment: You swapped the first $AB$ to $BA$.  What if you swapped the *middle* $BA$ to $AB$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(AB)^2=(AB)(AB)=A(BA)B=A(AB)B=(AA)(BB)=A^2B^2$$
After the third equal sign we introduced $AB=BA$.

Comment: If so it should be $(AB)^2=(AB)(AB)=((AB)A)B=(A(BA))B=(A(AB))B=((AA)B)B=(AA)(BB)=A^2B^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Just $$(AB)^2=ABAB=AABB=A^2B^2$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

$$ABAB$$
$AABB$ (by reversing the inner two)
$$A^2B^2$$